# FFmpegFrameGrabber deprecated pixel format error

Tags: video, ffmpeg, javacv

I tried to show the images my phone sends over WiFi with JavaCV and the FFmpegFrameGrabber class. Unfortunately I get this error, no matter which pixel format I set (tried from 0 up to 65).

```
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'http://IP:PORT/video':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 2:3], 24 tbr, 1200k tbn, 24 tbc    
[swscaler @ 0x7ff6cc3cba00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
```

This is how I create the FrameGrabber:

```
FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber("http://IP:PORT/video");
grabber.setFormat("mjpeg");
grabber.setVideoCodec(8);
grabber.setFrameRate(24);
```

And then getting the frame:

```
frame = grabber.grab();
```

**EDIT:**

Apparently this error comes from the ffmpeg library and has something to do with jpeg.

It is located in: libswscale/utils.c

Line 975 and 976 cause this error:

```
if(srcFormat!=c->srcFormat || dstFormat!=c->dstFormat)
     av_log(c, AV_LOG_WARNING, "deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly\n");
```

Unfortunately I am not skilled enough to delete/change this line. So I just ignore this messages as it doesn't affect the program. Unless someone can recompile an edited version of ffmpeg for mac :)

Comment: That's not an error, but a warning, and one you can ignore.

Comment: You're right, but it clutters up the console therefore it is hard to ignore.

Comment: You can change the loglevel to `error` and it will only show all errors, including ones which can be recovered from. See [docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).

Comment: Where would I do that? JavaCV uses ffmpeg from a .jar, so setting it in the console doesn't affect it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use avutil.av_log_set_level(avutil.AV_LOG_ERROR) to filter this warning.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpegLogCallback.setLevel(AV_LOG_ERROR)

org.bytedeco:javacv-platform:1.5.6